# Best web application testing tool for the following requirements?

Tags: testing

- Load HTML pages and check load speeds
- Verify completeness of HTML
- Follow links on the page
- Fill and submit forms
- Execute javascript and verify correctness of execution
- Verify AJAX calls by mocking the endpoint
- Allow flexibly defining tests and expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely everything from here [here](http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html#FUNC) will probably do. Until you give a few more requirements - language, free vs commercial, a little additional info about `Allow flexibly defining tests and expected results` etc this is your best chance.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use HtmlUnit.